# Custom language translation script in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, translation

I wrote a codeigniter helper function which helps to translate a string using the language files and default `lang()` helper.

The English language file with name `label_lang.php` is as given below.

```
$lang["label_country"] = "Country";
$lang["label_first_name"] = "First Name";
$lang["label_last_name"] = "Last Name";
$lang["label_email"] = "Email";
```

Currently other language files are not available. So I need to return the english string itself. I tried this in my helper function.

```
function translate_string($string_key)
{
    $ci = & get_instance();
    if (lang($string_key) == '') //this section is to return google translated text or as an alernative to language file
    {
        $ci->lang->load('label', 'english'); //load the English language file
        $string = lang($string_key); //get the English string
        $ci->lang->load('label', $ci->session->userdata('site_lang')); //reload the session language selected by user
        return $string;
    }
    return lang($string_key);
}
```

But this one doesn't seems to be working. I need to get the English string in this helper because I want to implement google/bing translator. I hope there must be a solution for this.

Comment: Why do you need such not real translate function ?

Comment: @Svetlio Else it will show a blank line instead of the desired text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily managed by copying the file to other language folders, and updating the string as required. Still answers are welcome.